# Calculating the row size of a table

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, row

Is there a way to calculate the row size (in bytes) of a particular table in postgresql / pgadmin3?

Comment: What would that measure? Especially in case of variable-width columns?

Comment: The question this one was linked to primarily deals with the size of a *whole table*. To get the (varying) size of individual rows: `SELECT pg_column_size(t) FROM tbl AS t LIMIT 10` [More info in this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql).